# Small labels in Outlook composing window

Tags: microsoft-outlook

A colleague suddenly found his Outlook composing window labels and text boxes "zoomed out". The text appears smaller than usual.

Here's how it looks normally:

[image]

While his now looks like this:

[image]

Any idea about how this can happen? I thought some keys/mouse combinations were to blame but found nothing.

Comment: Outlook probably uses system fonts and font sizes. These may have changed.

Comment: I must add that that's the only part of the UI where font size is smaller than usual

Comment: Is your Outlook fully patched? Does a repairing of your Office installation help?

Comment: Just restart Outlook.